# Sub-sections related to sections

Tags: formatting

I’d like to know whether it’s possible to improve the subsection style of my document. As you can see, I want to have up to four subsections in the “Methods” chapter. For example, the document shows “II. Selection of assets” when the ideal would be “I.II.  Selection of assets” (because it belongs to a particular chapter). Is this possible?

Here’s my code:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\flushbottom}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\bibliographystyle{nature}      
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm} 
\setlength{\parskip}{\the\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}                   
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
% All pages have headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} 
% Blank out the default header
\fancyhead{}
% Custom header text
\fancyhead[C]{ABC $\bullet$ ABC $\bullet$ ABC} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Allows customization of titles
\usepackage{titlesec} 
% Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.} 
% Arabic numerals for subsections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}.}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCE HYPERLINK SMALLER FONT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sffamily}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
% starts supressing the twoculomn environment, from here on it will we one column
\twocolumn[\begin{@twocolumnfalse}

% make a section
\section*{\huge\scshape\centering{The Mash-Up Experiment}}
\vspace{4mm}    
\normalsize

\begin{center}
\large\textsc{XXX XXX}\\
\vspace{4mm}  
University

\href{mailto:xxx@example.com}{xxx@killthepixelnow.com}
\end{center}
\vspace{6mm}

\section*{Abstract} 
“The Mash-Up Experiment” is a six-minute musical piece. 

\vspace{8mm}

%begins tabular
\begin{tabular}{p{1,5cm}p{12,55cm}p{1,5cm}}   
&\textbf{Keywords}: authorship\\
\end{tabular} 
% ends tabular

\vspace{11mm}

% ends suppressing the twocolumn environment, from here on it will be twocolumn
\end{@twocolumnfalse}]  

\section{Methods} % make section 
\subsection{Foundations}
In the matter of the sonic sources included in this song, more than thirty different tracks were utilised. The scope of genres and authors was motley, ranging from classical orchestration to bolero, from old singers to contemporary pop acts. Nonetheless, a great percentage of these tunes were taken from the works of James Bernard, who composed several scores for Hammer Films in the last millennium. He is the man behind the music from classic horror flicks such as “The Quartermass Experiment (1955),“ ”The Devil Rides Out (1968),” and “Scars of Dracula (1970).” 

\subsection{Selection of assets}
In the matter of the sonic sources included in this song, more than thirty different tracks were utilised. The scope of genres and authors was motley, ranging from classical orchestration to bolero, from old singers to contemporary pop acts. Nonetheless, a great percentage of these tunes were taken from the works of James Bernard, who composed several scores for Hammer Films in the last millennium. He is the man behind the music from classic horror flicks such as “The Quartermass Experiment (1955),“ ”The Devil Rides Out (1968),” and “Scars of Dracula (1970).” 

\subsection{Composition and arrangement}
In the matter of the sonic sources included in this song, more than thirty different tracks were utilised. The scope of genres and authors was motley, ranging from classical orchestration to bolero, from old singers to contemporary pop acts. Nonetheless, a great percentage of these tunes were taken from the works of James Bernard, who composed several scores for Hammer Films in the last millennium. He is the man behind the music from classic horror flicks such as “The Quartermass Experiment (1955),“ ”The Devil Rides Out (1968),” and “Scars of Dracula (1970).” 

\end{document}
```

Comment: just change `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}.}` to `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\Roman{subsection}.}`.  (it's not really a good idea to put the period at the end of the xsection definition -- it will go into cross-references if you use them with labels.)

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you know a better method to put a period after the section number? That was a solution I tried and worked, I didn't know it was not a good practice to do so.

Comment: i'm not really familiar with the koma-script document classes, but the manual (pp. 83-84) specifies a documentclass option `[numbers=endperiod]` that seems to provide that style.  if this works, i'll make it an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you want to take any actions?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ping!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Last chance to turn your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The desired behaviour

> I.II. Selection of assets

can be obtained by changing the following line

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}.}
```

to

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\Roman{subsection}.}
```

Although the caveats mentioned in the comments still apply.